# Distinct Counters in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

To get some distribution of a measure , we use counters in Cassandra i.e., similar to group by in mysql. But if I want unique distribution of a measure - how do I do that ?

Say I need daily distribution of users visiting a webpage - counters are very handy. Key will be day and value will be a counter. But for same webpage - If I need I need unique users distribution, how can I achieve using Cassandra?

I can implement it in various ways - Read before write, Offline processing etc.
I have also heard of bitmaps/hyper log log counters etc. Whats the easiest and simple solution that I can use in/on Cassandra to get unique daily distribution of users. I have volumes of couple of millions of events per day.

Example:

Say on 25/08/2013 - this is my webpage hits - user1, user2, user1, user3

On 26/08/2013 - user1, user2

On 27/08/2013 - user2, user3, user4

On 28/08/2013 - user1, user2, user1, user3

My output should be

> 25/08/2013 - 3 Unique users
>
> 26/08/2013 - 2 unique users
>
> 27/08/2013 - 3 unique users
>
> 28/08/2013 - 3 unique users

i.e., days vs unique users count.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot would depend on the performance requirements, consistency guarantees, number of systems etc (pretty much a standard).  That said I do have a recommendation if willing to have it probabilistic, and you dont need it instantly constantly upto date. HyperLogLog, as you mentioned is a great choice.

Each server could keep one in memory that as data is inserted it updates and periodically (ie once per minute) pushes to cassandra... or some other store.  Due to the nature of HyperLogLog, when you want to query it you can do a column slice of the servers hyperlogs and combine them.

```
ColumnFamilyHyperLogLogs: {
  someMetricsCardinalityRow20130828: {
    Server1: HyperLogLogBlob,
    Server2: HyperLogLogBlob,
    Server3: HyperLogLogBlob
  }
}
```

I would recommend clearsprings library thats worked great for us:

https://github.com/clearspring/stream-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/clearspring/analytics/stream/cardinality/HyperLogLog.java

It has the functionality to convert to byte array which you can use for serializing and deserializing and has methods available to combine them.

Alternatively, something that will take a lot more space is you could just have a row for each thing, like you say unique users.

```
ColumnFamilyName {
  uniqueUserOn20130828: {
   "user1" : null,
   "user2" : null,
   ...
  }
}
```

Then you can just call a count on the row and it will give you the exact number of unique users.  This is a lot more straight forward, easier to implement but it will take a *lot* more space but with the added benefit you can look at what users were actually there that day.  This can probably done pretty easy with CQL3 and sets

Comment: The second approach gives us unique users for a day. But I want to achieve group by functionality which means I need to multiple queries to get daily distribution. Can I achieve the same in a single query ?

Comment: If using thrift you can get them all in one query with a multiget_count.  Not sure the equivalent in CQL.  Hadoop can be used over cassandra too if want to do this in a more adhoc way.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing specific to Cassandra but if this data was modeled like below

```
date       user_id

25Aug2013    1
25Aug2013    2
25Aug2013    1
25Aug2013    3

26Aug2013    1
26Aug2013    2

27Aug2013    2
27Aug2013    3
27Aug2013    4

28Aug2013    1
28Aug2013    2
28Aug2013    1
28Aug2013    3
```

You can get uniques by day or by month or any other date format by doing

```
select count(DISTINCT user_id), date from <table_name> where date_trunc(date, 'month') =8 order by user_id, format(date, 'DDMMYYY) DESC/ASC
```

The date formatting is optional. You should be able to query across the table without that and then add appropriate filters.

Comment: I suppose, you mean group by ? If yes, then in Cass, group by doesn't exist :(

Comment: Nope not group by, I mean order by, because distinct will pick first of multiple distinct entries and that depends on the ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

A table definition of

```
CREATE TABLE user_day(
  day TEXT,
  user_id TEXT,
  user_count COUNTER,
  PRIMARY KEY (day,user_id));
```

Updated as follows:

```
UPDATE user_day SET user_count = user_count + 1  WHERE day = '20130829' AND user_id = 'USER-1';
UPDATE user_day SET user_count = user_count + 1  WHERE day = '20130829' AND user_id = 'USER-1';
UPDATE user_day SET user_count = user_count + 1  WHERE day = '20130829' AND user_id = 'USER-2';
UPDATE user_day SET user_count = user_count + 1  WHERE day = '20130829' AND user_id = 'USER-2';
UPDATE user_day SET user_count = user_count + 1  WHERE day = '20130829' AND user_id = 'USER-1';
UPDATE user_day SET user_count = user_count + 1  WHERE day = '20130829' AND user_id = 'USER-3';
```

would then give both :

```
SELECT * FROM user_day;

 day      | user_id | user_count
----------+---------+------------
 20130829 |  USER-1 |          4
 20130829 |  USER-2 |          2
 20130829 |  USER-3 |          1
```

and :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_day WHERE day = '20130829';


 count
-------
     3
```

WRT to comment, what you are looking for is a GROUP BY function which Cassandra does not support. You could look at a paid for option such as [Acunu](http://www.acunu.com/acunu-analytics.html) or [Datastax Enterprise offerings](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise/apache-hadoop). If you are looking for a free option then something like [amplabs spark and shark](https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/software/) is excellent for ad hoc queries, though I have not personally used them with Cassandra I know that it has been done.

Comment: It gives you unique users for a given day. To get unique users for another day, I need to query again. I need all unique users from 25/08 - 28/08 in one day and in above format

Comment: Cassandra != Relational Database. C* Data modelling generally favours storing your data according to how you wish to query it which will often lead to denormalised (according to relational thinking) structures. Cassandra is very good at supporting write scalability and high volume storage so don't be deterred from writing data in multiple ways as required for reading.

Comment: I am not bothered about writing date multiple times - I am bothered about getting my required data in one query - instead of multiple queries . In this case, in one query - how do I get all days unique counts ?